# realloc, two dimention allocation, leak and errors in valgrind

Tags: c, split, memory-leaks, valgrind, realloc

- I wrote a program to split given string according to certain delimiter. Everything **works fine** but there are **leak and error** in `valgrind`.
- `split` algorithm is correct.
- `substr` works fine.
- **My program**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** split(const char*, char, int*);
char* substr(const char*, int, int);
void freepath(char**, int);

int main(void) {
    char *str = "home///ubuntu//Desktop";
    char **path = NULL;
    int size = 0;

    path = split(str, '/', &size);

    freepath(path, size);
    return 0;   
}

char** split(const char *str, char c, int *size) {

    char **path = NULL;
    const char *save = str;
    int from=-1, i;

    if(str == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for(i=0 ; 1; ++i) {
        if(*str == '\0') {
            if(from != -1) {
                ++(*size);
                path = (char**)realloc(path, (sizeof(char**) *(*size)));
                *(path+(*size)-1) = substr(save, from, i);
            }
            break;
        }
        if(*str != '/') {
            if(from == -1)
                from = i;
        }
        else {
            if(from != -1) {
                ++(*size);
                path = (char**)realloc(path, (sizeof(char)*(*size)));
                *(path+(*size)-1) = substr(save, from, i);
            }
            from = -1;
        }
        ++str;
    }
    return path;
}

void freepath(char **path, int size) {

    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        free(*(path+i));
        *(path+i) = NULL;
    }
    free(path);
    path = NULL;
}


char* substr(const char *src, int m, int n)
{
    int len = n - m;
    char *dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

    for (int i = m; i < n && (*(src + i) != '\0'); i++)
    {
        *dest = *(src + i);
        ++dest;
    }
    *dest = '\0';

    return dest - len;
}
```

- **Valgrind output**:
  [image]
- What should be the reason ? , I really stuck with it !

Comment: substr() looks......flaky.  You mutate 'dest' after mallocing it.  Are you absolutely sure that substr()  always returns the pointer that you malloced?  If not, then you have leaked the allocation...  Can you not make a copy of 'dest' to return?

Comment: `split()` could be implemented easier using `strtok()`.

Comment: BTW, `*(x+i)` is equivalent to `x[i]`, and the latter is easier to understand.

Comment: `path = (char**)realloc(path, (sizeof(char)*(*size)));` --> Wrong size.  Try `path = realloc(path, sizeof *path * *size);`

Comment: The loop in `substr()` could be replaced with `strncpy()`. This is one of the few contexts where that's actually the right function.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, it works fine. I tested for more than one inputs and checked via valgrind as a seperate program. There was no leak or error after releasing allocated memory back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clang analyser has found 4 suspected points in your code:

1.

```
char *str = "home///ubuntu//Desktop";
```

needs `const` in front of `char` (pointer to const).

2.

```
char** split(const char *str, char c, int *size) {
```

contains an unused parameter (`c`).

3.

```
path = (char**)realloc(path, (sizeof(char**) *(*size)));
```

clang-analyser does not like `char**` as the argument of `sizeof`,  replacing it with `char*` removes the warning.

4.

```
path = (char**)realloc(path, (sizeof(char)*(*size)));
```

The same warning as in 3. Errr, no, not the same. Bingo! Replace `char` inside `sizeof` with `char*` and you're back home.

One final  remark. When you use valgrind, always add debugging information to the compiled code, that is, add `-g` to the compiler command-line options (gcc, clang, etc.). This will give you the information about the exact lines numbers  in your source code corresponding to the places where the problem was spotted by valgrind. My screenshot of your program under valgrind contains more information than yours:

[image: screenshot of valgrind]

Please notice that valgrind correctly identifies line 44 as the line with the buggy memory allocation (or line 45 with a buggy usage of the buffer allocated at line 44. Both options are a priori possibly correct).

Comment: *clang-analyser does not like `char**` as the argument of `sizeof`, which is strange, but replacing it with `void*` removes the warning* and *Replace `char` inside `sizeof` with `void*`*?!?  No.  There is no general guarantee that  a pointer will be the same size as a `void *`.  Just replacing pointers with `void *` to paper over warnings is a really bad idea.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Well, OK, your'e right, Pointers may have different lengths, it's implementation-dependent.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I edited the answer. Clang-analyser is right: only `char*` is OK if we need a pointer to `char*`.

Comment: Okay, i will try to fix and give a feedback about the result.